# Table-like output that wraps above the 2nd column if long

Tags: xslt, formatting, xsl-fo

So current use case I am trying to address is as follows.

I have a two column table and under certain circumstances (When the first is long enough) it needs to overlap the second column before breaking onto a second line, the 2nd column entry is then right aligned and on the second line

```
| Column A | Column B |
-----------------------
|Case one  |  Case one|
-----------------------
|Case two where the   |
|line breaks| Case two|
```

```
<xml>
  <block>
    <case>
      <caseonewords/>
      <caseone/>
    </case>
  </block>
  <block>
    <case>
      <casetwolongwords/>
      <casetwo/>
    </case>
  </block>
</xml>
```

The issue I am having is how I should go about formatting this to get the desired outcome. Have tried a number of things but have come up short, potentially was thinking floats but I haven't used them before very much. I'm not attached to using tables if there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the text with `fo:leader` and `fo:inline-container`, but I'm not sure how you'd do the borders of the 'table cells' without some of the borders doubling up:

```
<fo:block>Case one<fo:leader leader-length.minimum="0"
  leader-length.optimum="100%" keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
  keep-with-next.within-line="always" /><fo:inline-container
  width="50%"><fo:block text-align="right">Case
  one</fo:block></fo:inline-container></fo:block>
<fo:block>Case two where the line breaks<fo:leader
  leader-length.minimum="0" leader-length.optimum="100%"
  keep-with-previous.within-line="always"
  keep-with-next.within-line="always" /><fo:inline-container
  width="50%"><fo:block text-align="right">Case
  two</fo:block></fo:inline-container></fo:block>
```

Comment: No borders on the table cells so thats not a problem, will give your solution a try and see how it goes.